# nscanned nscannedObjects and n attribute values are equal in mongos explian command

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb for our Application .
I used mongodb profiler by setting up system.profiling level to 2 , did all my application  operations , exported all the records from system.profile and finally set the indexes on the collections  based upon the profiler result .

Now when i did  explain on those queries

**Query 1.**

```
db.stocks.find({ symbol: "GOOG", date: "2013-09-13",type: "O",Mini: false, rootsymbol: "GOOG" }).sort( { "price": 1,"call":1} ).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor symbol_1_date_1_type_1_Mini_1_rootsymbol_1_price_1",
        "nscanned" : 80,
        "nscannedObjects" : 80,
        "n" : 80,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "millis" : 2,
```

**Query 2.**

```
 db.stocks.find({ symbol: "NVO" }).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor symbol_1",
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "n" : 1,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "symbol" : [
                        [
                                "NVO",
                                "NVO"
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

I was confused of the results as the `nscanned` , `nscannedObjects` and `n` are always equal on all of my queries .

Please let me know if its an  issue if the nscanned , nscannedObjects and n values have equal values ??

Please let me know if i am missing something or if its a issue ??

Comment: It means you have quite good index usage for the find, however, not for the sort in the first query

Answer (score 2):

The fact that they are all equal mean you have good, uncovered, index usage.

I shall break down the results:

```
"nscanned" : 80,
```

This is number scanned in the index

```
"nscannedObjects" : 80,
```

This is the number of documents loaded after scanning the index, if this figure is higher than scanned then you could have bad index usage (depends on scenario).

The times `nscannedObjects` might be lower than nscanned is on a covered index or ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.nscannedObjects ):

> in the case of multikey index on an array field with duplicate documents.

```
"n" : 80,
```

This is the amount returned.

However, this does not mean you had a good result for the sort as shown in the first explain by:

```
"scanAndOrder" : true,
```

Comment: i see that scanAndOrder must be false so that it can use the index properly , but how can i change the query order as its happening on the application ??

Comment: @PreethiJain As I said in one of my last questions it isn't the client query order that matters, the problem is the huge index you have, until intersectioning is in (hopefully 2.6, fingers crossed) you have not got much choice

Comment: kmorris , Sammaye , thank you for clarifying . I was really worried until i got the clarification from you people .

Comment: @PreethiJain NP just be cafreful about the size of your unindexed sort, as I said in the comment in the other answer, MongoDB is limited when it comes to scanAndOrder

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is good - it is using the index to find the 80 matches that exist.  "n" is the number of documents returned; "nscannedRecords" is the number it needed to scan during the query (it could be less than 'scanned' if you have a covered query). "nscanned" is the number of index entries scanned (if an index could be used).  Sorting 80 records should be fairly quick; you don't have an index that you could use for it (from what you've shown us).

The second query is also great - it uses an index, and finds the one document that matches.

For more details on explain(), see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain-output-fields-core.

Comment: One good thing to note is that MongoDB is limited to about 32meg of sort without an index